# ArrayLIst in an object is not updating during Integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing

I have one service layer class which takes in a userId and add the userId to an arraylist in the Lobby object.I need to perform Integration test for this functionality. But somehow the code is not returning the updated arraylist to the test class. In service layer its working fine but when asserting the arraylist updated size, its failing.

Test module -

```
  @BeforeEach
public void setupLobby(){

    testUser = new User();
    testUser.setPassword("testName");
    testUser.setUsername("testUsername");

    testUser = userService.createUser(testUser);

    lobbyTest = new Lobby();
    lobbyTest.setName("testLobby");
    lobbyTest.setHostPlayerId(testUser.getId());

    lobbyId = lobbyService.createLobby(lobbyTest);



}

    @Test
public void addUserToLobby(){

    System.out.println("before ->"+lobbyTest.getPlayerIds().size());
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setUsername("user2");
    newUser.setPassword("password");

    newUser = userService.createUser(newUser);
    System.out.println("new user ->"+newUser.getId());

    lobbyService.addPlayerToLobby(lobbyTest.getId(),newUser.getId());
    System.out.println("after->"+lobbyTest.getPlayerIds().size());
    assertEquals(lobbyTest.getPlayerIds().size(),2);
}
```

Service method which I need to test

```
    public void addPlayerToLobby(long id, long userId){
    Lobby lobby = getLobby(id);

    System.out.println("service ->"+lobby.getId()+" "+lobby.getPlayerIds().size());
    if(lobby.getStatus()==1){
        throw new LobbyException("Game is in progress. You can't join lobby in the middle of the game. Please try later");
    }

    //Checking if the user exists before adding the user to lobby
    try {
        userRepository.findById(userId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new LobbyException(String.format("User with id: %d doesn't exist", userId));
    }
    String baseErrorMessage = "The lobby cannot have more than 7 player. Please join different lobby";

    System.out.println("service2->"+lobby.getId()+" "+lobby.getPlayerIds().size());
    //Size of lobby is limited to maximum of 7 players.
    if(lobby.getPlayerIds().size()>7){
        throw new LobbyException(baseErrorMessage);
    }

    //Player should be unique in the lobby
    if(lobby.getPlayerIds().contains(userId)){
        baseErrorMessage = "Player already exists in the lobby";
        throw new LobbyException(baseErrorMessage);
    }
    lobby.getPlayerIds().add(userId);
    saveOrUpdate(lobby);
    System.out.println("service3->"+lobby.getId()+" "+lobby.getPlayerIds().size());
}


    public Lobby getLobby(Long id) {
    Optional<Lobby> optionalLobby = lobbyRepository.findById(id);
    if (!optionalLobby.isPresent()) {
        throw new LobbyException(String.format("Could not find lobby with id %d.", id));
    }
    return optionalLobby.get();
}

public void saveOrUpdate(Lobby updateLobby){
    lobbyRepository.save(updateLobby);
    lobbyRepository.flush();
    System.out.println("service method ->"+updateLobby.getId()+" "+updateLobby.getPlayerIds().size());
}
```

For my testing I have put some print statement which clearly shows that its updating the arraylist in service layer but its not replicated in integration test method.

```
before ->1
new user ->3
service ->2 1
service2->2 1
service method ->2 2
service3->2 2
after->1
```

I am unable to get the issue. If there is some reference issue with the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd need to see the full source code to be sure, but it seems the Lobby object returned at:

```
Lobby lobby = getLobby(id);
```

is not the same object as the Lobby you set up in your test. 
You can confirm that by checking the object signature (toString()), their Hex codes are likely different.

Comment: Its returning different hex code 

testlobby hexcode is -
entity.Lobby@66dd1ad9

service layer hexcode is -

entity.Lobby@1b4bec0f

.And I have also updated the getLobby method in the code.

Comment: In that case, for your test to work you need to ensure it returns the same object, so that the player ID gets added to it. To do that you can mock the return value for lobbyRepository.findById(id); See [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html) for more details.

Comment: The thing is I want to do full integration test and don't want to mock any part of my code.

Comment: Ok, so the issue could be that lobbyTest does not get the property Id assigned when it's inserted at: lobbyId = lobbyService.createLobby(lobbyTest); Could you double check that lobbyTest.getId() has the same value as the added record, when you call : lobbyService.addPlayerToLobby(lobbyTest.getId(),newUser.getId());

Comment: Yes. both have same value. Regarding hex value, if they are different , it means we have two different instances?

Comment: So from what I can gather lobbyTest is a reference to the record being saved for the first time. It does not point to the updated record (the one with 2 user Ids). In order to make your test pass, you'd need to add something like lobbyTest = getLobby(id); before your assertion, then it will contain the 2 User ids.

Comment: I was also thinking to assert in this way. Thanks.